# Dropbox choose button does not return in ios8

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, dropbox, dropbox-api

I have developed an app using PhoneGap and need to integrate Dropbox for my users. I am currently using Cordova 2.9.
I have been unsuccessful in using the chooser dropin. Here is a brief explanation of what is going on...
From my phone gap app I launch **InAppBrowser** and point it to my server page that has the js API for the **chooser dropin**, this launches fine and if the user is not logged into Dropbox they are asked to login as expected. Once logged in the users files are displayed, so I think everything is good with my app key etc.

The problem occurs when the user selects a file and clicks the **choose** button. Nothing occurs, it seems like the success callback is never called. I have only noticed this when testing on an actual device running iOS8.

I have tried calling **alert** in the success callback and nothing happens, the chooser stays open. The **cancel** button also does not work in this scenario.

I was wondering if anyone else has experienced this issue, or has any advice for implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your implementation does work in iOS 7, this is likely this known issue:

https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=120846

Unfortunately, this is due to a bug in iOS 8, so it's up to Apple to fix.

Comment: Thank you, this looks like the problem. Thanks apple!