# Dropbox choose button return error message

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, dropbox, dropbox-api

I have developed an IOS app using PhoneGap and need to integrate Dropbox . I am using Cordova 3.1.0 under IOS 7.1.2 .

From my phonegap app I launch InAppBrowser and point it to my server page that has the js API for the chooser dropin, this launches fine and if the user is not logged into Dropbox they are asked to login as expected. Once logged in the users files are displayed, so I think everything is good with my app key etc.

The problem occurs when the user selects a file and clicks the choose button.   I got the message: `"Unable to close this window. Please close it manually and return to the previous site."`

I was wondering if anyone else has experienced this issue, or has any advice for implementation.

(almost the same issue as :
[Dropbox choose button does not return in ios8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26269297/dropbox-choose-button-does-not-return-in-ios8/26783642#26783642) - But with IOS7)

Comment: Cross-linking with the Dropbox API forum: https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=122841.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that PhoneGap's `InAppBrowser` doesn't support `window.close`. It might be possible for you to inject some JavaScript via your app that provides an implementation for `window.close`, or you might need to use the native browser instead of an embedded one.